# Use of Callback to return a Result Set from Web-SQL Database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-sql, jquery-callback

Below is my code and I want to return the `Result Set` and use it anywhere in my code. Last line also prints '0' but I want that value to contain the number of rows in the `Result Set`.
 How can I do this?

```
var querySql = function(sql, callback) {
    var tab = [];   
    db.transaction(function(tx) {       
        tx.executeSql(sql,[],function(tx, results){         
            for(i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
                tab.push(results.rows);                     
            }
        callback(tab);      
        });
    });
}

var queryLength = 0;
querySql('SELECT * FROM contacts', function(result) {
    console.log("RESULTS: " + result.length); 
    queryLength = result.length;
    console.log("QUERY_LENGTH: " + queryLength); 

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        alert("ITEMS: " + result[i].item(i)['firstname']);
    }   
});

console.log("QUERY_LENGTH_1: " + queryLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your `for` loop you need to access the item with the `item()` method, like so:

```
tx.executeSql(sql,[],function(tx, results){         
  for(i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
      tab.push(results.rows.item(i)); // <--------
  }
    callback(tab);      
});
```

That should populate `tab` with your records.

Also, your console statement needs to be within the `querySql` closure:

```
querySql('SELECT * FROM contacts', function(result) {
    //...
    console.log("QUERY_LENGTH_1: " + queryLength);
});
```

Otherwise it will be evaluated *first*, before the transaction has been executed on the next event loop.

Comment: Yeah, console statement outside is evaluated first, but somehow I want that value to be used outside.